# How can I load a specific ViewController within a scrollView using xib files?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scrollview, xib

I have a `scrollView` in the main `storyboard` connected to three different `ViewControllers` that are xib files that has page enabled vertical scrolling.

Everything works fine but I would like to know if there is a way to load a specific `viewController` first.

the `viewControllers` are as named:

> viewController1(notifications.xib)
>
> viewController2(newViewController.xib)
>
> viewController3(settings.xib)

the `ViewControllers` are loaded in ordered 1,2,3 so the scrolling can only be down from initial load.

> viewController1 <- this is the initial load when the app is build
>
> viewController2
>
> viewController3

I would like the initial load to be in the middle which is from `viewController` 2 so the scrolling can be up and down from initial load.

> viewController1
>
> viewController2 <- the initial load should be this when the app is build
>
> viewController3

this the code from the main `viewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

let notifications : notificationsView = notificationsView(nibName: "notificationsView", bundle: nil)
let newController : newViewController = newViewController(nibName: "newViewController", bundle: nil)
let settings : settingsView = settingsView(nibName: "settingsView", bundle: nil)

 self.addChildViewController(newController)
self.scrollView.addSubview(newController.view)
newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(notifications)
self.scrollView.addSubview(notifications.view)
notifications.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(settings)
self.scrollView.addSubview(settings.view)
settings.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

//size of frames
var newControllerFrame : CGRect = newController.view.frame
newControllerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
newController.view.frame = newControllerFrame

var settingsFrame : CGRect = settings.view.frame
settingsFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height * 2
settings.view.frame = settingsFrame

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * 3)
```

I hope this helps, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to start at the middle instead of the first?

If so, you do something like this.

```
CGPoint point = secondVC.frame.origin;

[scrollView setContentOffset:point animated: YES];
```